# ASP.NET Core OData Action with complex type having stream always returns null for the stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

Having asp.netcore odata service that returns an action with the following complex type that has stream property. The Asp.net core library versions are as follows:
[image]

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomerResponseConverter))]
public class customerResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath {get; set;}
    public Stream Photo{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the EDM model that is constructed:

```
   var action = builder.EntityType<company>().Action("exportCustomers");
   action.CollectionParameter<string>("customerIds");       
   action.ReturnsCollection<customerResponse>().;
```

Now there is a odata controller class that implements the following

```
    [HttpPost]
    public List<customerResponse> exportCustomers([FromRoute] string key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> custIds = parameters["customerIds"] as IEnumerable<string>;
        byte[] byteArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        List<customerResponse> responses = new List<customerResponse>();
        foreach (string id in custIds)
        {
            customerResponse itemResponse = 
                      new customerResponse() { Id = id, PhotoPath = "picture path", Name = "ABCD" };    
            responses.Add(itemResponse);
        }
         return new ContentResult()
         {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responses)
         };
    }
```

In the above controller implementation, the action returns a list of customerResponse. Now as part of the serialization, wanted to read the photo from the photo path and write directly to the json writer in the customeResponse.Stream.

The issue that I am facing is that the JsonConverter is never invoked. Hence unable to delay serialize the stream contents for the photo property.

Also In the above example after making the call, I always see the property Photo is not present. Only the Id,PhotoPath and Name are present in the deserialized response.

How can this be achieved ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use NewtonsoftJson to serialize and deserialize the data.

For example, in my API application (Asp.net 5), I installed these packages:

[image]

Then, in the ConfigureService method, register the service as below:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson().AddOData(opt => opt.Count().Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().SetMaxTop(5)/* other config */);
```

The Model like this:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Pincode { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MemoryStreamJsonConverter))]
    public Stream Photo { get; set; }
}
```

To Serializing and deserializing content of a MemoryStream can be achieved using a converter:

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
//using System;
//using System.IO;
public class MemoryStreamJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(MemoryStream).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var bytes = serializer.Deserialize<byte[]>(reader);
        return bytes != null ? new MemoryStream(bytes) : new MemoryStream();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var bytes = ((MemoryStream)value).ToArray();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, bytes);
    }
}
```

Create the following service to set the initial data:

```
public class EmployeeService
{
    public List<EmployeeModel> CreateData()
    {
        List<EmployeeModel> employeeModels = new(); // C# 9 Syntax  
        byte[] byteArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        employeeModels.Add(new EmployeeModel { Id = 1, Name = "Jay", Role = "Developer", City = "Hyderabad", Pincode = 500072,
            Photo = new MemoryStream(byteArray, 0, 4)
        });
        employeeModels.Add(new EmployeeModel { Id = 2, Name = "Chaitanya ", Role = "Developer", City = "Bangalore", Pincode = 500073,
            Photo = new MemoryStream(byteArray, 0, 4) });
        employeeModels.Add(new EmployeeModel { Id = 3, Name = "Bobby Kalyan", Role = "Developer", City = "Chennai", Pincode = 500074 }); 
        //...
        return employeeModels;
    }

    public List<EmployeeModel> GetEmployees() => CreateData().ToList();
}
```

The API Controller:

```
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly EmployeeService _employeeService;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService)
    {
        _employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    [HttpGet(nameof(GetData))]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult GetData() => Ok(_employeeService.GetEmployees());
}
```

Finally, after running the application the result is like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Tried the above. Its not hitting the MemoryStreamJsonConverter. There is one difference which is my controller is derived from ODataController instead of ControllerBase.

Comment: @Venki, I try to change the `ControllerBase` to `ODataController`, it still get the [same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZpFH.png). You can try to set a break point in the controller action method, whether the return data contains the steam or not? If still not working, can you tell us the project version and the odata version?

Comment: My project is targeting .NET Framework 5.0 and is using Microsoft.AspnetCore.OData 8.0.8 version and Microsoft.AspnetCore.Mvc.Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.0. In addition, the Newtonsoft.Json version 13.0.1.

Comment: Looks like JsonConverter is not used for json serialization and deserialization. See here the issue - https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/222. So need to find another way to do this.